# How do you load an image to use in a wpf page Edit-> and Clip a part of it

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been struggling with this for a few hours now.  I have had success a couple of times, but when I try to duplicate it I get varying results.  All I am trying to do is load an image as a static resource for use later on the same page.

I have tried everything contained in [Load Images in WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055121/load-images-in-wpf-application) and I have had no luck making it work.  I think maybe I am putting my images in the wrong place, though I don't know where else to put them.  I created a folder called Images.

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <BitmapImage x:Key="image1" UriSource="MyApp;component/Images/Image1.png" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="image2" UriSource="MyApp;component/Images/Image2.png" />

</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then Later on I use this

```
<Image Width=" 100" Height="100">
    <Image.Source>
        <CroppedBitmap Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=image1}">
            <CroppedBitmap.SourceRect>
                <Int32Rect X="0" Y="0" Width="100" Height="100" />
            </CroppedBitmap.SourceRect>
        </CroppedBitmap>
    </Image.Source>
```

Ultimately what I am trying to do is to display only part of an image, but I can't even consistently get an image on the screen let alone cut it into parts.

***Edit***

It seems that if I remove the CroppedBitmap mumbo jumbo the image does load by itself

```
<Image Width=" 100" Height="100" Source ="{StaticResource image1}">
```

So my entire problem is with the clipping.

Comment: I have tested (see response) with no issues.. Not sure where this is going wrong. Have you fixed your URI path?

Comment: Sorry Fixed?  I don't see a difference between yours and mine?

Comment: There is a leading `/` on the Uri source that is missing from yours.. (Check my sample)

Comment: It is throwing 'Initialization of 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.CroppedBitmap' threw an exception.' Line number '43' and line position '26'.I added that leading / and it made no difference.   It was throwing that error both before and after the change

Comment: What is the namespace for your application? Is your user control in another project trying to reference different projects?

Comment: No it is all in the same namespace.  I think I got it, It looks like I had multiple errors all getting in the way at the same time, so when I fixed one it had no effect, so I changed it back and fixed another.  The biggest issue is that image 2 was not set to build resource.  I wasn't using it, so I wasn't worried about it.  I think I have it working now, thanks for your help Nico.

Comment: Glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your images are stored in the directory `<solution>/Images/` and the full namespace of your application is `MyApp` then you can write your UriSource such as

`/MyApp;component/Images/Image1.png`

Now your images must have the `Build Action` set to `Resource` in the file properties. As per the image below.

[image]

The syntax for your URI string is

`/<full namespace>;component/<full path>/<file name with extension>`

I have tested your code with a cropped image and have this result with the code.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="image1" UriSource="/MyApp;component/Images/Image1.png" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="image2" UriSource="/MyApp;component/Images/se.png" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Image Width=" 100" Height="100">
            <Image.Source>
                <CroppedBitmap Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=image1}">
                    <CroppedBitmap.SourceRect>
                        <Int32Rect X="0" Y="0" Width="100" Height="100" />
                    </CroppedBitmap.SourceRect>
                </CroppedBitmap>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Project Layout**

[image: Project Layout]

**Sample Output:**

[image]